# Blender video editing: shortcuts for selecting video strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I use Blender 2.8 to cut videos and find myself selecting strips that I want to delete using my mouse - that's slow :( Often I cut a strip (Shift+K) and the strip on the wrong side of the cut gets selected (Apparently because my mouse cursor is located on the wrong side of the cut when the cut is performed.)

How can I quickly (i.e. via hotkey) jump to the strip on the other side of the cut and select it?

Answer (score 1):

Except moving the mouse cursor to the side you want selected before cutting(use K, unless you need a freeze frame), there is only this selection option, but it'll select all strips to the right of the playhead:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not quite what I was hoping for, as I would like to select only one neighboring strip. +1 anyway for taking the time to write an answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you always want to select the right strip after a split you can change the behavior of the split operator to do that: 
[image]

Comment: That sounds useful, thank you! :)